# Form API, Webform, or CCK?

Tags: forms

Which module is good to create forms, the Webform module, or the CCK module? Which is best suited to interact with the database?

I want to create a search form that displays a list of employees; each record has an edit, and a delete button. Clicking on "edit" would display the edit form.

Which one is good to use for this scenario?

Comment: This question is too general. Give an example of what fields you want to appear on the form and what the interaction is with the database.

Comment: I want to create a form for searching an employee and display records based on that. The records will have edit and delete buttons. On Edit it displays full record for editing.

Comment: @Dharmender, please edit your question and explain your scenario in more detail so we can understand your situation and help you. Do you want to implement a search filter that will work automatically or a form that will be reviewed by moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to define a content type (CCK) employee, then create a view that list your employees; in your case the search button will an exposed filter with criteria match any of the name, last name, job, or any field you want search for (you can have all of them at the same time to make search more easier).
By default views provide for administration a field named node edit link, and delete link so this will let you administrate your employees, but for more advanced administration of employees I advise you to use views bulk operation.

Webform will not gives you the possibility to do this; generally Webform is used for when you want to collect data from users and have statistic of it, like in a customer survey.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Views module for that; use exposed filters for the employees.

I have a similiar scenario running with events instead of employees.